# cfoutput over a PDF

Tags: pdf, coldfusion

What is the best way to cfoutput query results over a PDF? I need to be able to place the
results, ie name, address, etc. over an existing PDF letter for print.

Answer (score 4):

Make "name, address, etc." into fields, then fill in with `<cfpdfformparam>`.

see: http://cfpdf.blogspot.com/2008/04/populate-and-merge-multiple-pdf-forms.html

Comment: Hi Henry, Thank you for your help. I was able to get this to work with your suggestion. Would you happen to know how I can loop through my results and have this PDF display 5 times for my 5 results?                                                        <cfloop query="report"><cfoutput>
<cfpdfform action="populate" source="#ExpandPath('form/Overdraft.pdf')#">  
<cfpdfformparam name="Account" value="#f5#" >
<cfif  report.f15 eq 'Y'>
<cfpdfformparam name="Y" value="x">
<cfelse> 
<cfpdfformparam name="N" value="x"> 
</cfif> 
</cfpdfform> 
</cfoutput>
</cfloop>

Comment: create 5 individual PDFs, then flatten and merge them into one PDF with 5 pages? Or use <cfdocument> to create the PDF from scratch.

Comment: Btw if this works for you, time to mark it the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Found this on google: http://www.pdfcode.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2

(ABCPdf & ColdFusion)

I use ABCPDF for asp.net websites. I'm not sure how popular it is for ColdFusion.